# Python - Using lmfit to fit a function

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to use lmfit, but getting sporadic results for the parameters:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

x = [0.01,
0.02,
0.03,
0.04,
0.05,
0.06,
0.07,
0.08,
0.09,
0.1,
0.2,
0.3,
0.4,
0.5,
0.6,
0.7,
0.8,
0.9,
0.99999999,]

#some paramters to try to estimate
sigma1 = 6
scale1 = np.exp(5)

#generate values to use to fit
y = sp.lognorm(sigma1,scale=scale1).ppf(x)

#function set-up to use in lmfit
def invlognorm(params,x,data):
    sigma = params['sigma']
    mu = params['mu']

    model = sp.lognorm(sigma,scale=mu).ppf(x)
    return model - data

params = Parameters()
params.add('sigma', value= 1,)
params.add('mu', value= 1, )
# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(invlognorm,params, method = 'least-squares',args=(x, y))
```

and finally checking the results

```
result.params.pretty_print()
Name      Value      Min      Max   Stderr     Vary     Expr Brute_Step
mu        2.161     -inf      inf     None     True     None     None
sigma     6.754     -inf      inf     None     True     None     None
```

but these are nowhere near the original values.

Any help on what's going on here and how I can fix this so it gives reasonable results?

Comment: I suggest you look at a scatter chart of the points you generated, and overlay the fitted curve and the curve using the actual parameters and see if that gives you some insight. For example, it could be that your `x` just has too few points in it for the variance or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost certainly need better starting values for the `sigma` and `mu` parameters.

The `lognorm().ppf()` function diverges at `x=1`, giving huge values which will completely dominate any measure of misfit such as chi-square. 
In addition, small changes in parameter values will have essentially no effect on the total misfit, and all fitting algorithms will quickly give up. The huge value at `x=1` will also make any fit insensitive to the other data. Perhaps you actually meant some other method of `lognorm` such `pdf` or `cdf`?

If not, you may want to fit "in log space" -- fit the log of your data to the log of the model.  That will reduce the importance of the `x=1` datum.

Also, though it is *not* the cause of the problem, your fit did not actually use the `leastsq` method as your comment says.  To use the `leastsq` (Levenberg-Marquardt method) use:

```
# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(invlognorm, params, args=(x, y))
```

To use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` (which actually use trust region reflective use

```
# do fit, here with least_squares model
result = minimize(invlognorm,params, method='least_squares', args=(x, y))
```

(note spelling. Your example used `least-squares` which is not recognized, and so causes the Nelder-Mead method to be used).